# How to upload iPad build only in iTunes?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have developed an app which is only compatible  with iPad only . 
and I changed

```
Deployment info -> Devices -> iPad
```

I uploaded the build in iTunes , but it is not showing in iTunes ,

**My Question is** :

How can I upload build only with iPad compatiblity on iTunes ?

please help me .

Comment: Setting `Deployment info -> Devices -> iPad` means it is uploaded only for iPad. You don't have to mention in Itunes.

Comment: Down vote without comment ???

Comment: Just follow the [Apple Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload your build using Application Loader

Select

```
Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot , I uploaded using application loader now I am able to see build on iTunes